# Is Cross Validation enough to ensure that there is no Overfitting in a classification algorithm?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have a data set with 45 observations for one class and 55 observations for another class. Moreover, I am using 4 different features which were previously chosen by using a Feature Selection filter though the results of this procedure were somewhat strange..

On the other hand, I am using cross validation and getting good accuracy results (75% to 85%) from different classifiers since I'm using the classificationLearner on Matlab. Would this ensure that there is no overfitting? Or there might still be a chance for this? How can I assure that there is no overfitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on your training data set that you have available. If data that is available to you isn't representative enough, you will not get a good model regardless of the methods you use for training and validation.

Having that in mind, if you are sure your data is representative (has the same distribution of values for any subset of "important" attributes as the the global set of all data) than cross validation is good enough to rely on.